# Trouble getting GWT plugin to install and work correctly in Eclipse (4.3 Kepler) under OS X 10.8

Tags: java, android, eclipse, macos, eclipse-wtp

I've searched around but don't see an answer for the problem I'm seeing. Hopefully someone here may know:

In OS X 10.8.5, after a few unsuccessful attempts of getting the Google Plugin for eclipse to work (in eclipse 3.7 - Indigo), I removed eclipse and reinstalled its latest version (4.3 - Kepler), retaining none of the prior versions preferences or workspace. I then installed the CDT plugin and built a familiar C project, just to verify eclipse is installed and working correctly.

Then, returned and attempted the [instructions](http://www.gwtproject.org/usingeclipse.html) for installing GWT (both using the "p2 repository" method, as well as the `"local zip file`" method as described in the FAQ's).

Neither way results in being able to establish a new web application project: File > New > Web Application Project, from the Eclipse menu as reported in the various instructions... I don't get an error message of any kind, simply not able to locate `"New > Web Application Project".`

I'd like to create some nice looking dashboards using dynamic graphics on a web page, and the GWT tools look ideal for this... Can anyone please assist me in determining what else I can try.

Thanks in advance,

Walt

Comment: ...After removing the CDT plugin, and also reinstalling the WTP and GWT (http://www.gwtproject.org/usingeclipse.html) without reinstalling CDT, I'm able to launch a "New > Web Application Project" wizard.  However when entering **any** name in the Package filed, the following error is displayed: "The selected App Engine SDK is not valid: Failed to initialize App Engine SDK at  /eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.6/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.6/"

Comment: SOLVED - got this working by manually downloading the GWT SDK and AppEngine SDK for Java from [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/download.html) then under Eclipse > Preferences > Google replace the AppEngine and Web Toolkit with the downloaded versions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a Java JDK installed and that your eclipse is configured to use it `Eclipse > Preferences > Java`

My App Engine error disappeared after I installed the latest Oracle JDK. I'm also using OS X 10.8.5. See [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-java/zIw439VSe-I) google group topic for more info.